# How to fix error Cannot load vendor library [libfbclient.dylib or libfbembed.dylib]

Tags: macos, delphi, firebird

I am trying to get my FireMonkey application to run on Mac OS against a Firebird database.

All runs perfectly under Windows, but under Mac, I get this error:

> Cannot load vendor library [libfbclient.dylib or libfbembed.dylib].
>   Hint: check it is in the PATH or application EXE directories, and has
>   x86 bitness.

I cannot find any help on how to fix this.

Can anyone give any suggestions?

I have installed 64 bit Firebird, 32 bit Firebird and the lipo version to no avail.

Comment: "I have installed... 32 bit firebird.." Are the dylibs included in the install? If so, add them to the deployment using the Deployment Manager in Delphi, and set the Remote Path to Contents\MacOS